# Compositions of prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

This question is related to numbers found in the OEIS sequence [A191837](https://oeis.org/A191837).

In this sequence, $a(2) = 48 = 5 + 7 + 17 + 19$, where the summands of 48 are all prime numbers that are less than or equal to $48/2=24$.  The prime factors of 48 are $2^4$ and $3$, and neither $2$ nor $3$ are summands in $a(2)$.  Similarly, $a(3) = 108 = 5 + 7 + 11 + 19 + 29 + 37$ and the prime factors of $108$ ($2^2$ and $3^3$) are not summands in $a(3)$.  This appears to hold for all fourteen (verified and unverified) integers in the sequence.

Is there some way to prove or disprove the conjecture that for every integer in sequence [A191837](https://oeis.org/A191837), the prime factors of $a(n)$ will never be an element of the summands of $a(n)$?

Comment: I'm not sure how you are defining the sequence, but the headline definition in Oeis is "Least even number m which can be written as sum of 2n primes p[1] < ... < p[2n] < m/2 such that m-p[i] also is prime for i=1,...,2n." and the last condition would imply that none of the summands is a factor. But if you have got your sequence from a different place it might not be obvious that the definitions are the same.

Comment: @mark  Sorry, which condition?  I am trying to extend the sequence and looking for ways to reduce the workload.  If it is true that the factors will NEVER be an element of the summands then I can remove them from the list of candidate summands.  Removing even just a few candidates will speed up the search.

Comment: "m-p[i] also is prime for i=1,...,2n", so p[i] cannot be a factor of m unless m=2p[i], and that is excluded by p[i]<m/2.

Comment: Is it obvious that $a(n)$ exists for every $n$?

Comment: @mark  Got it.  If instead, the restriction on p[i] were relaxed to p[i]<=m/2, then there would be the additional case where 2 and m/2 would be candidates, whenever m==2*prime.  But would relaxing the restricting be a bad thing? In the "COMMENTS" section, it says: "Moreover, we restrict these summands to be the lesser one of the decompositions p+q=m", and this would still hold, even if p[i]=m/2.  Or am I wrong about that?

Comment: @andrea I don't know.  But given that m can become arbitrarily large, I would be surprised if it weren't true for all n.

Comment: I have extended this sequence by more that 200 terms.  Does anyone want to *try* to independently verify my results?  This was a challenging problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, it's easy to prove the statement. In fact, the greatest common divisor of $a(n)$ and any of the summands $s$ in $a(n)$ has to be equal to one - they have to be relatively prime.

If they were not relatively prime, then we could look at the greatest common divisor $g>1$ of $s$ and $a(n)$. If $g<s$, then $s$ wouldn't be a prime because it would have a divisor $g$, and such composite $s$ isn't allowed as a summand of $a(n)$ in the sequence.

If $g=s$, then we couldn't prove that $s$ is non-prime. However, $a(n)-s$ would also be a multiple of $g$ but we would have $a(n)-s > a(n)/2 > g$, so $a(n)-s$ wouldn't be a prime which would again violate the condition that both the summands $s$ and the differences $a(n)-s$ have to be prime for the elements $a(n)$ of your sequence (check the page you linked to carefully how the numbers are defined).

Not only you can omit candidate summands of $a(n)$ that are prime factors of $a(n)$: you may omit all candidate summands that fail to be relatively prime with $a(n)$. Well, truth to be told, it's almost the same thing if you know that the summands have to be prime.

Comment: Thanks Lubos!  I just needed to be certain that removing the factors of m wouldn't cause erroneous results, and now I am.